# What does ' \ ' followed by a non-escape character do?

Tags: regex

I came across someone doing: `grep -v "\#"`. Could someone just quickly explain what happens when you precede a character that is not an escape character (like '`#`') with a backslash.

Comment: @KenWhite I don't see what I'm looking for :/

Comment: https://regex101.com/ is of great help.

Comment: I do not think that this is a good duplicate simply because I searched for backslash as used in this question in the linked answer but found no answer there. And while it is possible that the linked answer describes `\` + `literal character` it is not easily discoverable. Additionally the comments under the linked answer share the same sentiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\#` is a regular expression which matches the literal character `#`. Infact the backslash is not needed since the regular expression `#` is simpler and serves the same purpose.

Comment: Correct.  In the context of a regexp, a backslash before anything *other than* a letter or number is treated as forcing that character to be literal, and if that character happens to not be special, it does nothing.